# Does anonymous class have its own jvm?

Tags: java

I have been a question in an interview that **every class in java have its own JVM** ,does **anonymous class also does have its own JVM**?help me understanding this concept.

Comment: It is really strange question. Probably was mean only *.class file.

Comment: Every application will be allocated with an instance of JVM.. by application, it can be a stand-alone Java class also.. not sure about every class..

Comment: *"every class in java have its own JVM"* ? No. You're probably confused somewhere.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. The JVM is an executable *container* (n executable process, .exe etc.) that runs the Java programs, and all the classes are loaded *within* the JVM.

Typically each class would have it's own `.class` (e.g. `Example.class`) file, and that would include anonymous classes (which would appear as `Example$1.class`, `Example$2.class` etc.).

Comment: As you said Example$1.class ,so its still a class so the ans would be yes?

Comment: A class *is not* a JVM. A JVM is an actual executable that runs applications consisting of .class files